# USB speakers don't work under ubuntu

Tags: usb, speakers

I have USB speakers which work perfectly fine under Windows, with no setup required. Under Ubuntu, absolutely nothing happens when the usb is connected. Under Configuration -> Sound -> Output, the USB speakers do not show up.

Now, it's my first time posting here. I understand that linux is supposed to be a superior alternative to Windows, but, in order for it to work properly, people interested in the OS should contribute when they see flaws such as this one. So the question is twofold: one, how could I solve the problem for me, and two, how could I solve the problem for everyone. In my years of experience with Ubuntu, as a not-a-powershell-user, I have the impression that the OS is not very transparent and that it is very hard to get access to what is happening under the hood, that is, ubuntu seems in many aspects to be as much of a blackbox as Windows, and to have a "just works" philosophy (except when it doesn't). But maybe I'm missing something important.

Comment: Unplug the speakers and watch the command `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in the speakers.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please clarify if the speaker's input is an aux cable and you have another usb cable just for power, or you have only one cable that needs to be connected to the computer and it is a usb cable.